# Nunit testing collection for null value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I got this file to That I have to write an nunit test on::

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CollectionsLib
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOJ { get; set; }  
    }

    public class EmployeeManager
    {
        private static readonly List<Employee> employees;

        static EmployeeManager()
        {
            employees = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee { EmpId=100, EmpName="John",DOJ=DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5),Salary=30000},
                new Employee { EmpId=101, EmpName="Mary",DOJ=DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2),Salary=10000},
                new Employee { EmpId=102, EmpName="Steve",DOJ=DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2),Salary=10000},
                new Employee { EmpId=103, EmpName="Allen",DOJ=DateTime.Now.AddYears(-7),Salary=50000},
            };
        }

        public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return employees;
        }
        public List<Employee> GetEmployeesWhoJoinedInPreviousYears()
        {
            return employees.FindAll(x=>x.DOJ<DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is:

1. If I had to write a scenario to test that there is no null value in this collection, how do I go on about doing it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
[Test]
public void GetEmployees_Should_NotReturnAnyNulls()
{
    var manager = new EmployeeManager();
    var employees = manager.GetEmployees();

    foreach(var employee in employees)
    {
        Assert.NotNull(employee);
    }
}
```

Or even better, with the nuget FluentAssertions like this:

```
[Test]
public void GetEmployees_Should_NotReturnAnyNulls()
{
    var manager = new EmployeeManager();
    var employees = manager.GetEmployees();
    employees.Should().NotContainNulls();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To test that a list has no null members, you can use several forms of assertion in NUnit, listed in my personal order of preference...

```
Assert.That(someList, Is.All.Not.Null);
Assert.That(someList, Has.None.Null);
Assert.That(someList, Has.All.Not.Null);
Assert.That(someList, Does.Not.Contain(null);
CollectionAssert.AllItemsAreNotNull(someList);
```

In each case, `someList` is the list you want to test.

If you check the docs at https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/intro.html, you may find other options as well! Take your pick! :-)